# return remember_user_token of Devise on API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, remember-me

I have Rails app with Devise and it has login API of iOS app.
User model is rememberable.
My iOS app use webview to view rails app as web site,
and so
I want to return user's **remember_user_token** (on web browsers, devise seems to set it to cookies automatically) from login API.

In login API, I want to get **remember_user_token**, but I don't know how to.

```
user.remember_token
```

is 20 characters, but on web browser, **remember_user_token** in cookies is 114 characters. It seems to they are difficult.
Devise or Rails encrypt token?

Code of my app is here.

## models/user.rb

```
# Table name: users
#  remember_created_at        :datetime
#  remember_token             :string(255)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :encryptable, :rememberable, :confirmable, :trackable, :recoverable, :timeoutable
end
```

## api/sessions_controller.rb

```
module Api  
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    layout false
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
      catch(:warden) do
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)

        render json: { remember_user_token: remember_user_token }
        return
      end

      render json: { error: "error message" }
    end
  end
end
```

Any advise will be appriciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I think cockies value is encrypted using salt, so it's larger.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! cookies.signed seem to be eocrypted.